# Error 1105 (Insufficient space on the file group). How do you troubleshoot this issue?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am restoring a database from a full-backup. The restores operation runs for 3-4 hours and failed with an error 1105 (Insufficient space on the file group). And the database went to suspect mode. How do you troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: @mohan111 if you think that is sufficient for an answer, you should post it as an answer. If not, at least expand into what the article is trying to say.

Comment: if I think it is the answer I will post that in the box itself. I just gave him the reference link so he can  have a better view of his problem. Instead of replying me give more answers in SO and it will help you to move up ranks @ragingasiancoder

Comment: @Mohan111- I think  ragingasiancoder raised valid point, you should have answered in short and then provided a link or article to refer the solution in detail

Comment: @mohan111 The reason I said the above is that StackOverflow is to gather valid information, if not useful solutions. By providing the article details, you help make StackOverflow what it is intended for: to provide a central gathering of information. Also, I likely commented (there's a lot of posts I review) because your article also seemed like spam; from the lackadaisical view, it sure seemed like it was spam. As it appears, it also seems to have been removed.

Comment: @mohan111 Also, my first comment said, `If not [sufficient for an answer], expand into what the article is trying to say`. You don't need an answer for that, as comments are made exactly for what you wouldn't put in an answer. You know, I find it better use of my time to actually use SO for its purpose of enlightenment rather than the shallow purpose of gaining "internet points".

Answer (score 1):

You can actually add a new data file on another drive and rerun the restore operation using the system stored procedure “sp_add_data_file_recover_suspect_db”. Parameters are the same as while creating a new data file.